# FileServer .net core logging and force download

Tags: c#, .net-core, fileserver

I'm currently trying to write a simple file server to server file for another webapi or services.

I have one mandatory requirements, I need to get every request/download log in a file.
And also on the basic fileserver middleware broad by Microsoft, you don't download the image for example.
It's just showing the image.
Is there a way to force download and also change the logging behavior ?
I tried to put a middleware to log requests, but is only log when there is directory changement.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles",
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

Comment: Even to display, technically browser is downloading it first, but I think [this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) is what you are after.

Comment: _"i'm currently trying to write a simple file server to server file for another webapi or services."_ - for fun and excercise? There's nginx, IIS, Apache, ... all of which can serve static files out of the box. All widely used, tested and decently secure(able). AFAIK all of which can log requests.

Comment: _"Is there a way to force download"_ If the image is a static file (like "someimage.jpg") Browser _will_ download it in order to render it. It just won't end up in "Downloads" folder. Is that what you want? Do you still want to have it rendered or "just" downloaded?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help.
This is not for exercice, this is for production usage. Replacing python file server.
My goal is to make the file end up in the download folder.
And i wish to use .NET core, but you right we might be able to server this out of the box. I will consider your answers ! Thank you so much !